# Why my new font is not used and why coming back to my old one does not work anymore?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was using Fira Code and wanted to try the new MS font called Cascadia. For some reason VS Code did not apply that new font and put a default ugly one.

Then, I put back Fira Code, but for some weird reason, even that one was no more applied!

I tried to reinstall VS Code, but did not solve my problem.

Any suggestions for me?

Running VS Code 1.38.1

Thanks

Comment: That new font is "Cascadia Code" - is that what you used?  Not just "Cascadia".

Comment: @Mark, I tried both. But do you understand why Fira Code does not work anymore?

Comment: No, I have used both with no problems.  I can switch back and forth without even having to reload vscode.  `"editor.fontFamily": "Cascadia Code",` or `"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to fully understood what happened, but now it is working.

First, I changed user and workspace font family to Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace

Then, I did: Cascadia, 'Fira Code', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace

Working good now.